# Is it possible in AWS CodeCommit to put restriction on child branches?

Tags: amazon-web-services, git, github, amazon-iam, aws-codecommit

AWS Code-commit
For example : There is a repo named as : repo1
There are 4 branches named as : master - backup - testing - development

Scenario is : Restrict the dev user, that he should not create a child branch from any other branch like testing, backup or main. Only he can create branch from the Development branch.

I think its not possible  because there is no permission for feature branches.